# How to set a new window into a GroupBox in QT?

Tags: c++, qt, qt6

I have a Window with a `Group Box` called `Function control box`

[image]

I want to include this window into that group box

[image]

I do that by using this code

```
ui->functionControlBoxGroupBox->setParent(componentIdentification);
```

Where `componentIdentification` in an `UI` object of the window above.

But it seems that nothing happens. Why?

This is what happening. From this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

**Question:**

How can I import a complete window form into a group box in QT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually, the group box is supposed to be the other window's parent (not the opposite), thus you should do:

```
componentIdentification->setParent(ui->functionControlBoxGroupBox);
```

A better way to do the same thing: set a layout to the parent (the group box) and add the child window **to the layout**, i.e., in construction:

```
ui->functionControlBoxGroupBox->setLayout(new QGridLayout());
```

somewhere else, later:

```
ui->functionControlBoxGroupBox->layout()->addWidget(componentIdentification);
```

This way, the group box is automatically set as the component's parent.